# Why did David's kingdom split if he didn't sin?

Tags: sin, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, king-david, maseches-shabbos

According to one opinion in the [Gemara (Bab. Shab. 56b)](http://dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=shabbos&daf=56b&go=Go), the reason David's kingdom split was because he sinned by believing Lashon HaRa'. According to another opinion, though, he never sinned at all. According to the latter opinion, why did the kingdom split?

---

**This question is part of the [Daf Yomi Challenge](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1325/5).**

Comment: Why do have to find a fault in David? Perhaps it's Shlomo's fault. Or Rechavam.

Comment: What about the Psalms, like Ps 51?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on that Gemara it appears that there are two opinions regarding whether King David erred or not. According to the opinion that he did err, this shortcoming was the cause of the split in the kingdom and the ultimate exile while according to the opinion that he did not err the split in the kingdom must be attributed to some other cause.

Based on Kings 11:11-13 it seems that the simple understanding is that King Solomon sinned (or erred in some way) and therefore deserved to have the Kingdom completely taken away from him. However, because of the honor due to King David, God did not remove the kingdom from King Solomon but rather from his son. Additionally, because of the merit of King David and Jerusalem Solomon's descendants would be left one tribe - Judah.

Comment: (and Benjamin, See v23.) http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et09a12.htm, +1

Comment: the kingdom split because tax was too high.